# How to set a visual state on a nested element?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to set a value to a property using VisualStateManager. The problem is I need to set this value on a nested element (called variableSizedWrapGrid), but it doesn't respond to the corresponding state. The idea is when the user change the orientation for the tablet (LANDSCAPE to PORTRAIT) and should change the orientation for this element.

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VariableSizedWrapGrid x:Name="variableSizedWrapGrid" Orientation="Vertical" Background="Blue" Width="660" ItemHeight="120" ItemWidth="220" Margin="0,0,80,0">

            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Orientation)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Horizontal" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        </VariableSizedWrapGrid>

    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

I'm developing a Windows Metro Application for Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what the LayoutAwarePage is for. If you have a LayoutAwarePage as a base class, and you want a control to switch VisualStates when the tablet is rotated, then you hook the control's Loaded event to the StartLayoutUpdates method on the LayoutAwarePage.

As you can see, whenever the state changes, it will run "InvalidateVisualState" which will go through all the controls that receive LayoutUpdates, and manually set their VisualStateManager to the appropriate state.

So in the code you have there, you need to set a VisualState for the landscape - which I believe would be called FullScreenLandscape but I can't remember - and then add StartLayoutUpdates to the Loaded event of the VariableSizedWrapGrid control. This is assuming your page is a LayoutAwarePage. Which, honestly, you should make it so if you want to do this. They've included all that boilerplate code for this reason.

Hope that helps.